# jQuery mobile button on enter or spacebar

Tags: jquery-mobile, event-handling

I have a simple button that needs to be pressed (for accessibility reasons on desktop) by using the enter or spacebar keys. The following is what I have:

```
$("#return-home").on("tap", function () {
    window.location.reload();
});
```

In addition to "tap" I need an event for enter and spacebar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#return-home").on("tap keypress", function (e) {
     if(e.type == "tap" || e.which == "13" || e.which == "32") {
          window.location.reload();
     }
});
```